# What type of entropy encoder does the MATLAB save() function use? I.e. how does that function work?

Tags: matlab, encoding, compression, huffman-code

I am working on a compression project, and I used the default save() function in Matlab for the purpose of lossless (entropy) encoding. The transform module is all figured out.

I used the save() function to encode a 3d array that includes a bunch of zeros. I am sure that Matlab is using some kind of lossless compression with the save() function since, when I save that array, it ends up taking far less space than an array, say, containing no zeros at all. I had no success finding out what type of entropy encoding schemes are behind the function. Because it is a core part of the algorithm, I think I must at least know what is behind the function.

Plus, if you know any other type of entropy encoder that would do a better job in compressing a 3d array that contains zeros, I would really appreciate you sharing. Or, if you think I could easily write the code for that myself, then please let me know.

Comment: If you are trying to reduce memory use on matrices with a lot of zeros, sparse arrays might be what you are looking for. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [v7 format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf) uses deflate.

The v7.3 format uses the HDF5 format, which supports gzip (deflate) and szip compression. It also has an option to not compress.

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB `save` function [supports compression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#btox10b-1-version) for some of the formats that are available. Specifically, `-v7` (default format) and `-v7.3` support compression. The details of the compression are not documented.

Comment: Python has a library that can read mat files, checking its documentation or codes can be helpful. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html